# How to simplify my list of numbers?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, statistics, jupyter-notebook

What I have here is a list of x values with its corresponding cumulative density value with a specific lambda. What I need to do is find the mean of `exc_cdf1` values shown...

How can I possibly put these `exp_cdf` values into an array so that I can use the function of `array.mean()`?

Is my way of coding in order to display the `exp_cdf1` a good way to approach such problem? (i need to print the values so I can have a sanity check, to an extent.) If we were to continue with the way I'm doing it right now where i have the loop displaying all of its values, how can I find the mean?

Lastly, I want to find the mean of such `exp_cdf1` values but in an efficient and intuitive way, I hope I made myself clear.

here is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(50)/50
for i in range(0,50):
    lambda1 = 0.5  
    exp_cdf1 = 1 - lambda1 * math.exp(-1 * lambda1 * arr[i])
    print(' lambda1 = ' , lambda1, ' ' , i , " = " , arr[i], 'exp_cdf1 = ' , exp_cdf1)
```

[this is what displays when the code is ran:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2cMM0.png)

edit:

after updating the code in which i learned that i can just simply exp_cdf1.mean()

i then have this code:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(50)/50

for i in range(0,50):
    lambda1 = 0.5

exp_cdf1 = 1 - lambda1 * math.exp(-1 * lambda1 * arr[i])

print('lambda1 = ' , lambda1, i , " = " , arr[i], 'exp_cdf1 = ' , exp_cdf1, ' mean = ' , exp_cdf1.mean())
```

in which i get an error

[AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'mean'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJYjd.png)

Comment: post the stack trace as text please and not as an image.

Comment: for Q1: did you try googling *"numpy array from list?"*

Comment: So what i see here, is i can use np.array() to convert a list into an array, so does that mean all i'd have to do is np.array(exp_cdf1) ?

Answer (score 1):

`numpy` allows you to make operations on the whole array. It also re-defines the functions from the `math` module to allow for this (including `exp`). So you can just write:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(50) / 50
lambda1 = 0.5
exp_cdf1 = 1 - lambda1 * np.exp(-lambda1 * arr)
print(exp_cdf1.mean())
# 0.604560034105
```

Note that the value of `lambda` also never changes. If it did, it would still work if `lambda1` was a `numpy` array (or actually any iterable) of the same length as `arr`.

Comment: so does that mean exp_cdf1 is already in the form of an array and thus i can just do exp_cdf1.mean()?

Comment: In my textbook here, it says that i can either write import numpy and/or import numpy as np Would that in any shape or form change the updated answer you just wrote?

Comment: @cavell If you write `import numpy`, you would have to replace all occurences of `np.` with `numpy.`. So  instead of `np.arange`, it would be `numpy.arange`, `numpy.exp` instead of `np.exp` and so on (if you have more code). It is just a way to give the module a different (usually shorter) name.

Comment: @cavell If you have further questions, you can always [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Code formatting in comments is barely readable.

Comment: @cavell Well, your "updated code" is basically your old code, instead of the one I posted. It does not work, because your `exp_cdf1` is a `float` and not a `np.array` of `float`s. A `float` has no `mean` method.

Comment: so does that mean the for loop included in my code is why i am not allowed to us the mean method?

Comment: @cavell Just use the code I posted. There is no need for a loop here. Unless you want a running average, in that case you should really ask a new question.

Comment: @cavell I mean what do you expect `mean(0.5)` to return (for example)? A `mean` makes only sense if you have a sample.

Comment: @cavell Also, replace `math.exp` with `np.exp` in your code.

Comment: Well since we're in the numpy module, the exp_cdf1 is already an array, therefore exp_cdf1.mean() would work in terms of finding the mean of the list/array, so i'm just confused as to what specifically part of my code that makes this error come up?

Comment: @cavell The `math.exp` and the `arr[i]`. The latter is a single `float` (and `i` is still set to the last index from the `for` loop) and `math.exp` returns a single `float` as well. Replace `math.exp` with `np.exp` and `arr[i]` with `arr`. Just like in my code.

Comment: I am still very confused, sorry.